# How to form a nested javascript object using a string with dots as property hierarchy

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have a mapping object in which property and Value looks like below :

```
var obj = {
     key: "key1.key2.key3.key4"
};
```

How to convert `obj` to nested javascript object as shown below:

```
var returnObj = {
       key1: {
            key2: {
                   key3:{
                        key4: {
                              "value": key
                        }
                   }
            }
       }
};
```

Comment: Basically that mapping object contains many keys (values as strings).. So accordingly the returnObj will be nested with number of objects inside..

Comment: What did you try yourself before posting this question?

Comment: do you really swap key and value parts?

Comment: Why is t his tagged as java?

Comment: `java` != `javascript`

Comment: *"Are there any other solutions"* Other than what? I see no initial/reference solution in the question, so any solution we might give, could easily be the one you already have. To not waste our time, edit question and show what you have, and explain why that is not good enough.

Comment: @Andreas what i meant by "Are there any other solutions" is rather than taking a mapping object can we achieve the same returnObj?

Comment: No, your question stated a requirement for how you want the object to look. I see no "solution" for converting the first to the second, and that seems to be what you're asking about. If not that, edit the question and clarify it.

Comment: @Andreas Sorry.. I currently do not have any solution. I need one..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate the keys and then split the string for single properties. Then create objects, if not exists. Later assign the original key as value.

```js
function convert(object) {
    var result = {};
    Object.keys(object).forEach(function (k) {
        object[k].split('.').reduce(function (o, k) {
            return o[k] = o[k] || {};
        }, result).value = k;
    });
    return result;
}

var obj = { key: "key1.key2.key3.key4" };

console.log(convert(obj));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

With last key as key.

```js
function convert(object) {
    var result = {};
    Object.keys(object).forEach(function (k) {
        var path = object[k].split('.'),
            last = path.pop();
       
        path.reduce(function (o, k) {
            return o[k] = o[k] || {};
        }, result)[last] = k;
    });
    return result;
}

var obj = { key: "key1.key2.key3.key4" };

console.log(convert(obj));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: and if i want to have like this object ->var returnObj = {
       key1: {
            key2: {
                   key3:{
                        key4: key
                   }
            }
       }
}; how will the above code change?

Comment: then you need to save the last splitted value and take it as value , instead of `.value =`.

Comment: Thank you so much!